# Duvida comando Require

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, require

Estou tentando usar o comando require mas esta dando erro, estou tentando usar no seguinte código:

```
var Parser = require('C:/Users/gabri/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/faculdade/Supervisorio_P1/polo/teste/Scripts/node_modules/jsonparse/jsonparse.js');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Está dando erro no require, alguém sabe o por que?

Comment: Você já tentou colocar o caminho a partir da pasta que está o arquivo que você está modificando? Pois você está utilizando o caminho completo. Poderia ser algo assim: var Parser = require('../jsonparse.js');

Answer (score 1):

Quando você vai fazer um require de algum módulo no Node.js, você não passa onde ele se encontra e sim o nome do módulo, no seu caso o `json-parser`

Exemplo

```
var Parser = require('json-parser');
```

O Node.js já procura dentro da pasta `node_modules` o módulo com esse nome e já define na variável esse módulo, no seu caso variável `Parser`

Pronto agora você já pode usar as funções do módulo `json-parser` chamando a variável `Parser`

Exemplo

```
Parser.NomeDaFuncao();
```

Caso tenha mais alguma dúvida sobre esse pacote acesse o site [clicando aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-parser)